Part c) Interpreting the result for the tangent to the curve $xy = 1$ also being normal to the curve $ 27y^2 = 4x^3$
The full question:
a). Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $xy = 1$ at the point $(t, \frac{1}{t})$.
b). Find the equation of the normal to the curve $ 27y^2 = 4x^3$ at the point $(3u^2, 2u^3)$.
c). Show that just one tangent to the first curve, other than an asymptote, is also a normal of the second.
Parts a) and b) are ok, but I stumble on the meaning of the result in part c). Workings so far:
a). At point $(t, \frac{1}{t}) \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-1}{t^2} \dots (1)$
$ \therefore$ equation of the tangent line:
$ \underline {t^2y + x - 2t = 0}$ $\dots (2)$
b). At point $(3u^2, 2u^3) \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2 \times (3u^2)^2}{9 \times 2u^3} = u $; the slope of the tangent to the curve.
$\therefore$ gradient of Normal through point $(3u^2, 2u^3)$ is $ \frac{-1}{u} \dots (3) $
$ \therefore$ equation of the normal line: $\underline {uy + x - 2u^4 -3u^2 = 0}$ $\dots (4)$
c). If the tangent line from the first curve $xy = 1$ is normal to the second curve $ 27y^2 = 4x^3$, the gradients must be equal.
Equating gradients from $(1)$ and $(3)$ $ \Rightarrow\frac{-1}{t^2} = \frac{-1}{u} \Rightarrow u = t^2 \dots (5) $
The equation of the tangent line to curve $xy = 1$ must be equal to the equation of the normal line to the curve $ 27y^2 = 4x^3$.
$\therefore$ from $(2)$ and $(4) \Rightarrow t^2y + x - 2t = uy + x - 2u^4 -3u^2 $
Cancelling $x$ both sides, and cancelling $t^2y$ both sides (since $u = t^2$),
$\Rightarrow - 2t = - 2u^4 -3u^2 $
$\Rightarrow 2u^4 + 3u^2 =2t \dots (6) $
With $u = t^2$ , $\frac{1}{t^2}u = 1$ and $\frac{u^2}{t^4} = 1 \dots (7)$
Dividing $(6)$ by $t^8$ and using results in $(7)$ finally gives:
$2t^7 + 3t^3 = 2$
(Or, $t^3(t^4 + 3) = 2$)
Not sure how to interpret this result. Any comments most welcome. Thanks!

"From $(1$) and $(3)$, ..." It should be $-\frac{1}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{u}, u=t^2$. You can arrive to this quicker as one tanget should be perpendicular to the other so $-\frac{1}{t^2} \cdot u=-1$

You showed the only possible values of $t$ are the one(s) that satisfy $2t^7+3t^3=2$. And that equation obviously has only one real solution. What more do you need?

Thanks David. So I suppose in the context of the question; 'Show that just one tangent to the first curve, other than an asymptote, is also a normal of the second', this means that t does not equal 0, and t = 0 is an asymptote?
